# Bootstrap Modal Popup validation is not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I open a HTML form in Bootstrap Modal Popup and apply Bootstrap validation it's work fine but when I open same form and fill with json data Bootstrap validation not works.

Below is my function

```
specialtyDetail = {
params: [],
Load: function (params) {
    specialtyDetail.params = params;
    specialtyDetail.ValidateSpecialty();
    specialtyDetail.LoadSpecialty();
},


LoadSpecialty: function () {
    if (specialtyDetail.params.mode == "Add") {

    }
    else if (specialtyDetail.params.mode == "Edit") {

        specialtyDetail.FillSpecialty(specialtyDetail.params.SpecialtyId).done(function (response) {

            if (response.status != false) {

                var specialty_detail = JSON.parse(response.SpecialtyFill_JSON);
                var self = $("#specialtyDetail");
               self.bindMyJSON(true, specialty_detail);
                if (specialty_detail.chkActive == 'True')
                    $("#specialtyDetail #chkActive").attr("checked", true);
                else
                    $("#specialtyDetail #chkActive").attr("checked", false);

                specialtyDetail.ValidateSpecialty();

            }
            else {
                utility.DisplayMessages(response.Message, 3);
            }
        });

    }
},
 ValidateSpecialty: function () {
    $('#frmSpecialtyDetail')
       .bootstrapValidator({

           message: 'This value is not valid',
           excluded: [':disabled'],
           feedbackIcons: {
               valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
               invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
               validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
           },
           fields: {
               ShortName: {
                   group: '.col-md-6',
                   validators: {
                       notEmpty: {
                           message: 'Short Name is required'
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       })

    .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        specialtyDetail.SpecialtySave();
    });
}
```

Below is my HTML form.

```
<div id="specialtyDetail" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-sm">
    <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="specialtyDetail.UnLoad();"><span class=" red" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Specialty</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="tblspecialtyDetail">

                <form id="frmSpecialtyDetail" method="post">
                    <!--start - CONTENTS-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Short Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input class="form-control size100" name="ShortName" id="txtShortName" type="text" maxlength="10" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 pad-a-labelsize">
                            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="chkActive">
                                <label for="Active">Active</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="txtDescription" type="text" maxlength="55" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 pad-a-labelsize-btn">
                            <div class="btn-block">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="btntest" onclick="specialtyDetail.test();" >Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my bind json function.

```
bindMyJSON: function (bAuto, myJson) {
    var self = this;
    self.loadDropDowns(true).done(function () {
        self.selectDropDowns(bAuto, myJson);
    });
    self.loadLabels(bAuto, myJson);
    self.selectCheckBoxes(bAuto, myJson);
    self.loadTextBoxes(bAuto, myJson);

    self.find('[type=hidden],[type=text], textarea').each(function () { this.defaultValue = this.value; });
    self.find('[type=checkbox], [type=radio]').each(function () { this.defaultChecked = this.checked; });
    self.find('select option').each(function () { this.defaultSelected = this.selected; });

    var html = self.html();
    //for (prop in myJson) {
    //    var regex = new RegExp("{@" + prop + "}", "g");
    //    html = html.replace(regex, myJson[prop]);
    //}
    this.html(html);
}
```

I hope I get any help in this matter because I am stuck here and can't find any help. Why my validation not works when I open form in Edit mode and fill it.

Comment: did you try calling specialtyDetail.ValidateSpecialty(); immediately after loading html into DIV. i don't see that in bindMyJson function..

Comment: Yep I have tried as you can see above when i Load form in Edit mode after bindMyJSON junction i Called specialtyDetail.ValidateSpecialty(); and one more thing the same thing worked when I used Jquery UI modal popup but that is not responsive thats why I used bootstrap modal popup and I stuck here.

Comment: ya i got your point now, would you be able to replicate problem of your code in jsFiddle. Possibility of getting solution is more via jsfiddle.

Comment: when I called validate function under  this.html(html); line it works but when i called after bindMyJSON(); function it's not working why any reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try re-initializing the validator after this line

```
this.html(html);
```

**Update**

```
$('#frmSpecialtyDetail')
   .bootstrapValidator({

       message: 'This value is not valid',
       excluded: [':disabled'],
       feedbackIcons: {
           valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
           invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
           validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
       },
       fields: {
           ShortName: {
               group: '.col-md-6',
               validators: {
                   notEmpty: {
                       message: 'Short Name is required'
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   })
```

Run these after tat line

Comment: How can I re-initializing, can you please help.

Comment: yep it worked but that is my general function why it is not working if i called my validate function after this function.

Comment: are you asking for an explanation?

Comment: when you run `this.html(html);` it deletes the old html and replaces with the new one (the events which are attached along with that will also get deleted). so, you have to tell the system to re attach the events to those elements